# Not able to generate unique id of duplicate node value in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Below is my input xml and I want to generate output based on supp-part-number.Currently if the supp-part-num is duplicate then it not generate separate block. I mention below is current output and expected output format.

**Input xml:**

```
     <array-list total="4">
        <catalog-publish-vO rec-no="1">
            <short-desc>NLCTVBL Cable Clips - Round Cable 5-7mm Black</short-desc>
            <err-msg>2</err-msg>
            <supp-part-num>1101</supp-part-num>
        </catalog-publish-vO>
        <catalog-publish-vO rec-no="0">
            <short-desc>NLCTVBL Cable Clips - Round Cable 5-7mm Black - 1050151244 (100 Pack)</short-desc>
            <err-msg>2</err-msg>
            <supp-part-num>1101</supp-part-num>
        </catalog-publish-vO>
        <catalog-publish-vO rec-no="1">
            <short-desc>NLCTVBL Cable Clips - Round Cable 5-7mm Black</short-desc>
            <err-msg>2</err-msg>
            <supp-part-num>1101</supp-part-num>
        </catalog-publish-vO>
        <catalog-publish-vO rec-no="0">
            <short-desc>NLCTVBL Cable Clips - Round Cable 5-7mm Black - 1050151244 (100 Pack)</short-desc>
            <err-msg>2</err-msg>
            <supp-part-num>1101</supp-part-num>
        </catalog-publish-vO>
    </array-list>
```

**Current output:**

```
     <array-list exceeds="" total="4">
        <catalog-publish-vO>
            <part>part_1101</part>
            <pendingItem>
                <description>
                     Description :
                    NLCTVBL Cable Clips - Round Cable 5-7mm Black</description>
            </pendingItem>
            <approvedItem>
                <description>
                     Description :
                    NLCTVBL Cable Clips - Round Cable 5-7mm Black - 1050151244 (100 Pack)</description>
            </approvedItem>
            <pendingItem>
                <description>
                     Description :
                    NLCTVBL Cable Clips - Round Cable 5-7mm Black</description>
            </pendingItem>
            <approvedItem>
                <description>
                     Description :
                    NLCTVBL Cable Clips - Round Cable 5-7mm Black - 1050151244 (100 Pack)</description>
            </approvedItem>
        </catalog-publish-vO>
    </array-list>
```

**Expected output format:**

```
     <array-list exceeds="" total="4">
        <catalog-publish-vO>
            <part>part_1101</part>
            <pendingItem>
                <description>
                     Description :
                    NLCTVBL Cable Clips - Round Cable 5-7mm Black</description>
            </pendingItem>
            <approvedItem>
                <description>
                     Description :
                    NLCTVBL Cable Clips - Round Cable 5-7mm Black - 1050151244 (100 Pack)</description>
            </approvedItem>
            </catalog-publish-vO>
            <catalog-publish-vO>
            <pendingItem>
                <description>
                     Description :
                    NLCTVBL Cable Clips - Round Cable 5-7mm Black</description>
            </pendingItem>
            <approvedItem>
                <description>
                     Description :
                    NLCTVBL Cable Clips - Round Cable 5-7mm Black - 1050151244 (100 Pack)</description>
            </approvedItem>
        </catalog-publish-vO>
    </array-list>
```

Here is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="kTXLifeRequest" match="catalog-publish-vO" use="supp-part-num/text()"/>
    <xsl:key name="kTXLifeRequest1" match="catalog-publish-vO" use="concat(supp-part-num,'#',@rec-no)"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select=
                 "catalog-publish-vO[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kTXLifeRequest',supp-part-num)[1])]" >
<xsl:value-of select="'TEst For Loop: '"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="exceeds">
                    <xsl:value-of select="//array-list/@exceeds" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:if test="//array-list/@exceeds='Y'">
                    <xsl:attribute name="message">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'There are too many matching items to display fully. Only the first 2000 matching items are available for viewing.'" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:attribute name="total">
                    <xsl:value-of select="//array-list/@total" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:if test="err-msg = '2'">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:variable name="group" select="key('kTXLifeRequest',supp-part-num)" />
                        <xsl:for-each select= "$group" >
                        <xsl:value-of select="'current position:'"/><xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                                <part>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('part_',supp-part-num)" />
                                </part>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="@rec-no = '0'">
                                <approvedItem>
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="err-msg != '0'">
                                            <xsl:call-template name="CatalogDetails"></xsl:call-template>
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <supplier-part-number>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="concat('part_',supp-part-num)" />
                                            </supplier-part-number>
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                </approvedItem>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="@rec-no = '1'">
                                <pendingItem>
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="err-msg != '1'">
                                            <xsl:call-template name="CatalogDetails"></xsl:call-template>
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <supplier-part-number>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="concat('part_',supp-part-num)" />
                                            </supplier-part-number>
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                </pendingItem>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select=
                 "catalog-publish-vO[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kTXLifeRequest1',concat(supp-part-num,'#',@rec-no))[1])]" >
                <xsl:variable name="group"
                                  select="key('kTXLifeRequest1',concat(current()/supp-part-num,'#',current()/@rec-no))" />
                <xsl:for-each select= "$group" >
                    <xsl:if test="err-msg != '2'">
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:if test="@rec-no = '0'">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="err-msg = '0'">
                                        <part>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="concat('part_',supp-part-num)" />
                                        </part>
                                        <approvedItem>
                                            <supplier-part-number>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="concat('part_',supp-part-num)" />
                                            </supplier-part-number>
                                        </approvedItem>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="@rec-no = '1'">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="err-msg = '1'">
                                        <part>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="concat('part_',supp-part-num)" />
                                        </part>
                                        <pendingItem>
                                            <supplier-part-number>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="concat('part_',supp-part-num)" />
                                            </supplier-part-number>
                                        </pendingItem>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="unspsc-description">
        <xsl:param name="unspsc"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length(substring-after($unspsc,'|')) &gt; 0">
                <td title="{substring-after($unspsc,'|')}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($unspsc,'|')"/>
                </td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($unspsc,'|')"/>
                </td>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="CatalogDetails">
        <xsl:variable name="partNum" select="supp-part-num" />
        <xsl:variable name="recNum" select="@rec-no" />
        <xsl:if test="//catalog-publish-vO[supp-part-num = $partNum and @rec-no != $recNum ]/unspsc-code != unspsc-code" >
            <unspsc-code>
                UNSPSC Code :
                <xsl:value-of select="unspsc-code" />
            </unspsc-code>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="//catalog-publish-vO[supp-part-num = $partNum and @rec-no != $recNum ]/short-desc != short-desc" >
            <description>
                 Description :
                <xsl:value-of select="short-desc" />
            </description>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="//catalog-publish-vO[supp-part-num = $partNum and @rec-no != $recNum ]/UOM != UOM" >
            <UOM>
                UOM :
                <xsl:value-of select="UOM" />
            </UOM>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="//catalog-publish-vO[supp-part-num = $partNum and @rec-no != $recNum ]/unit-price != unit-price" >
            <currency-code>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(unit-price,'.')">
                        Unit Price :
                        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(unit-price,'##,###,##0.00####')" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        Unit Price :
                        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(unit-price,'##,###,##0.00')" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                <xsl:value-of select="currency-code" />
            </currency-code>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="//catalog-publish-vO[supp-part-num = $partNum and @rec-no != $recNum ]/supplier-name != supplier-name" >
            <supplier-name>
                Supplier Name :
                <xsl:value-of select="supplier-name" />
            </supplier-name>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="//catalog-publish-vO[supp-part-num = $partNum and @rec-no != $recNum ]/manufacturer-name != manufacturer-name" >
            <manufacturer-name>
                Manufacturer Name :
                <xsl:value-of select="manufacturer-name" />
            </manufacturer-name>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="//catalog-publish-vO[supp-part-num = $partNum and @rec-no != $recNum ]/manf-part-num != manf-part-num" >
            <manf-part-num>
                Manufacturer Part Number :
                <xsl:value-of select="manf-part-num" />
            </manf-part-num>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="//catalog-publish-vO[supp-part-num = $partNum and @rec-no != $recNum ]/tech-specs != tech-specs" >
            <tech-specs>
                Technical Specification :
                <xsl:value-of select="tech-specs" />
            </tech-specs>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="//catalog-publish-vO[supp-part-num = $partNum and @rec-no != $recNum ]/min-order-qty != min-order-qty" >
            <min-order-qty>
                Min Order Qty :
                <xsl:value-of select="min-order-qty" />
            </min-order-qty>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="//catalog-publish-vO[supp-part-num = $partNum and @rec-no != $recNum ]/max-order-qty != max-order-qty" >
            <max-order-qty>
                Max Order Qty :
                <xsl:value-of select="max-order-qty" />
            </max-order-qty>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="//catalog-publish-vO[supp-part-num = $partNum and @rec-no != $recNum ]/lot-size != lot-size" >
            <lot-size>
                Pack Size :
                <xsl:value-of select="lot-size" />
            </lot-size>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="//catalog-publish-vO[supp-part-num = $partNum and @rec-no != $recNum ]/omni-class != omni-class" >
            <omni-class>
                Omni Class :
                <xsl:value-of select="omni-class" />
            </omni-class>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="//catalog-publish-vO[supp-part-num = $partNum and @rec-no != $recNum ]/additional-details != additional-details" >
            <xsl:variable name="additionalDetails">
                <xsl:for-each select="additional-details/item">
                    <xsl:call-template name="LoopNodes">
                        <xsl:with-param name="tCount" select="count(.)"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="var" select="'1'"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:for-each select="additional-details/item">
                <xsl:attribute name="title">
                                        Additional Details :
                    <xsl:value-of select="$additionalDetails" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="." /> |

            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="LoopNodes">
        <xsl:param name="tCount" />
        <xsl:param name="var"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$var &lt; $tCount">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/> |
                <xsl:call-template name="LoopNodes">
                    <xsl:with-param name="tCount" select="$tCount"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="var">
                        <xsl:number value="number($var)+1"/>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/> |
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could we have the xslt you're using ? Could help a lot to help ;-)

Comment: Actually, i'm not understanding your expectation either...
Based upon what conditions do you want a separate catalog-publish-vO element is outputted ? (really need the xslt code)

Comment: Please minimize your example to only what's necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Hi, Eric thanks for your reply, I want to identify difference item from the catalog and abov file there are two catalog-vo for the same item I will identify based on supplier part number and @rec-no.

Comment: Hi Eric, my dout is that if supp-part-num is duplicate then key() will generate unique key or not? <xsl:key name="kTXLifeRequest" match="catalog-publish-vO" use="supp-part-num/text()"/>